# Branding Issues - JS Injections

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

In our attempt to transform our code from FTC to CAM we are facing some minor difficulties from the branding perspective. I’ll briefly elaborate about our scenario below:

- In our current FTC implementation we are using both CSS and JS to render the desired UI. References for both the assets are present in the master page and hence get rendered with the HTML
- Since it is recommended not to modify the master page when moving to vNext, we decided to go via the custom actions route.
- We added custom actions for both CSS and JS to a test site. On browsing to our test site, we found out that the UI was appearing as desired but only with a noticeable lag.
- As it appeared, what was happening was that the corev4.css was getting applied and then after around 2 seconds our custom CSS would be applied leading to an unpleasant flickering effect.
- I went through a project named Branding.CustomCSS present in the PnP samples which did a similar thing of applying the CSS by rendering link tag via a custom action. In the documentation for that project, it was mentioned that this wasn’t a recommended approach for applying CSS if we are on Office 365 or April 2014 CU on-prem. Instead, the AlternateCSS approach was recommended.
- I modified the code to use the AlternateCSS approach for rendering the CSS reference while keeping the custom action for rendering JS reference as it is. That certainly improved the experience.
- We still had the JS file though which was manipulating the DOM to achieve the desired look and feel and that was still loading with a delay. We suspect that this is happening because in case of Custom Actions the code to insert JS references runs after the page is loaded. While the JS loads and executes, the UI that is shown meanwhile is without the DOM manipulations and is not what is desired. So the flickering of some components in the page, that the JS is responsible to beautify, is still present. This was not the case in our FTC where there was no noticeable lag.

I required some suggestions as to what approach we should follow so that we can do away with the delay in loading such asset files? 
Also, is there an approach that would render JS references along with the HTML and not after page load like it does in case of custom actions?

Comment: try look up information about
RegisterSod()
SP.SOD.registerSodDep()
SP.SOD.loadMultiple(), it helps you load js file in a more logic way

Answer (score -2):

I too are experiencing this issue. It is a really ordinary user experience. As you said, you can limit it by updating the logo and applying the alternate CSS in the provisioning process, but you still get that noticeable flicker. I have been experimenting with adding ms-hidden to the body tag at the start of the process, then removing it at the end, but it hasn't helped much. I might see about hiding the body from the get-go via the alternate css, then in the injector.js file override that style. Any suggestions from others would be greatly appreciated though. The PnP only has a basic injector scenario where it puts a message in the status area, but that isn't really a realistic scenario.

Comment: This is not an answer. If you want to make comments, use comments section.